# Write entity bean contents to db before transaction commits

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions, glassfish, ejb

I'm using GlassFish v2ur1 (it's the one our company uses and I cannot upgrade it at this point). I have an EJB (ejbA) which gets called periodically from a timer. In the call, I'm reading a file, creating an entity bean for each line, and persisting the entity bean to a db (PostgreSQL v9.2). After calling entitymanager.persist(entityBean), an HTTP call is made to a servlet, passing the entityBean's ID, which in turn calls into another EJB (ejbB). ejbB sends a JMS message to another entity bean, ejbC. This is a production system and I must make the HTTP call, it processes the data further. ejbC is in the same enterprise application as ejbA, but uses a different EntityManager. ejbC receives the id, reads the record from the db, modifies the record, and persists it.

The problem I'm having is the entity bean's data isn't stored into the db until the transaction from the timer call completes (see below) (I understand that's the way EJB's work). When ejbB is called, it fails to find the record in the db with the id it receives. I've tried a couple of approaches to get the data stored into the db so ejbC can find it:

1) I tried setting the flush mode to COMMIT when persisting the entityBean in ejbA:

```
- em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT)
- instantiate entity bean
- em.persist(entityBean)
- em.flush()
```

However, the results are the same, by the time ejbC is called, no record is in the db.

2) I created ejbD and added a storeRecord method (which persists entityBean) in it with TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW. This is supposed to suspend ejbA's transaction, start ejbD's transaction, commit it, and resume ejbA's transaction. Again, the results here are the same, by the time ejbC is called, no record is in the db. I'm also seeing a problem with this solution where the ejbA call just stops when I call the storeRecord method. No exceptions are thrown, but I don't see the EJB processing any more lines from the file even though there are more lines. It seems to abort the EJB call and roll back the transaction with no indications.  Not sure if this is a GlassFish v2ur1 bug or not.

How can I ensure that the data is stored into the db in ejbA so when ejbC is called, it can find the record in the db? BTW, there are other things going on in ejbA which I don't necessarily want to commit.  I'd like to *only* persist the entityBeans I'm trying to store into the db.

ejbA

```
ejbTimer called (txn starts)
read file contents
for each line
   create entity bean
   persist entity bean to db
   make HTTP call to ejbB, passing id
   <see ejbC>
return (txn ends)
```

ejbB

```
Processes data based on id
Looks up JMS queue for ejbC
Passes ejbC the id
```

ejbC

```
ejb method called (txn starts)
read record based on received id
modify record and persist
return (txn ends)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I did to solve this.  1) I added remote methods to ejbB which perform the same functionality as the HTTP call. This way the call to ejbB is within the same transaction.

The root of the problem, which Glenn Lane pointed out, is that the transaction continues in the call from ejbA to ejbB, but it ends when ejbB sends the JMS message to ejbC...the transaction doesn't extend to the call to ejbC. This means when the id gets to ejbC, it's in a new transaction, one which cannot see the data persisted to the db by ejbA.

2) I stored the entity bean to the db in ejbA in a special state. The entity bean will be stored when the timer call to ejbA returns (and therefore txn commits). When ejbA is called again by the timer, it looks for record in the db in this special state. It then calls ejbB. ejbB sends a JMS message. When ejbC gets the id, it finds the record in the db (as it was previously committed in a previous txn), changes it's state, and continues processing.

Answer (score 0):

When using a transaction isolation of "read-committed", no other transaction can see changes made by an uncommitted transaction.  You can specify a lower transaction isolation, but this will have no effect on PostgreSQL: it's "most chaotic" behaviour is read-committed, so you simply can't do it with PostgreSQL.  **And nor should you**:

ejbA should *not* call ejbB via HTTP.  Servlets should only be used to service remote client requests, not to provide internal services.  ejbA should connect and invoke ejbB directly.  If the method in ejbB is annotated `TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY` or `TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED`, ejbB will see the entity created by ejbA because it is under the same transaction.

In ejbB, persisting is unnecessary: simply load the entity with an `EntityManager` and make the change.

If you are completely at the mercy of this HTTP mechanism, you could use bean-managed transactions, but this is a terrible way of doing things:

```
read file contents
for each line
    start transaction
    create entity bean
    persist entity bean to db
    commit transaction
    make HTTP call
```

Comment: Glenn, thanks for the response.  I changed my code to add a Remote Interface to ejbB which ejbA now calls (after persisting the entityBean) instead of using HTTP. However, the behavior I'm seeing is that ejbB cannot find the entityBean ejbA persisted, so it creates a new one.  The example I gave was simplified.  ejbA calls ejbB after persisting the entityBean.  But ejbB sends a JMS message to another EJB, call it ejbD and ejbD performs the lookup of the entityBean and creates a new one if it isn't found.  I don't think this changes anything as it all still executes within the same transaction.

Comment: Is it best to update the example to include ejbD and JMS, create a new question, or just leave the information in the comment?

Comment: If ejbD is invoked by JMS (it's a message-driven bean for instance), ejbD will -not- run in the same transaction as ejbB.  It could end up running before ejbB finishes.  It sounds like whatever work ejbD is doing should be called directly, not deferred via JMS.

Comment: I see. I cannot call ejbD directly. There is a bunch of additional work being done when ejbB is called which needs to occur first. Any suggestions as to how I can commit an entityBean within ejbA so when a call to ejbB->ejbD is made and ejbD queries for it it will be found? The example above, which was my attempt at a work-around for it, does not work.